# React not rerender on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have some react code below. The picross component creates a grid of blocks. When I click one of the buttons it doesn't change the size of the grid, what am I doing wrong?

```
const [size, changeSize] = useState(15);

  console.log(size)
  return(
    <>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div className = "wrapper row">
      <div className='buttons col s2' >
        <h5>Game size</h5>
        <button className='btn' onClick={()=>{changeSize(5)}}>5x5</button>
        <br/>
        <button className='btn' onClick={()=>{changeSize(10)}}>10x10</button>
        <br/>
        <button className='btn' onClick={()=>{changeSize(15)}}>15x15</button>
        <br/>
        <button className='btn' onClick={()=>{changeSize(20)}}>20x20</button>
        <br/>
        <button className='btn' onClick={()=>{changeSize(25)}}>25x25</button>
      </div>
    
    <Picross 
      rows={size}
      cols={size}
      >
...
```

I am new to react and don't know much about hooks. Is there a different way I am supposed to do this?

Edit: Picross component

```
    function Picross({ rows, cols }) {
       // console.log(rows, cols);
  let temp_g = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    temp_g[i] = new Array(cols);
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      temp_g[i][j] = i + j;
      // temp_g[i][j]= <Node num={i+j}></Node>
    }
  }

  var [grid, updateGrid] = useState(temp_g);
  

  return (
    <div className="grid col s9">
      {grid.map((row) => (
        <div className="blockrows">
          {row.map((val) => {
            
            return <Node num={val}></Node>;
            </div>
          })}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: Thanks for the help problem solved, I no longer use useState in my Picross component. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your `Picross` component might have some issues. Not nearly enough here to go off of. Please consider making a runnable example that shows the actual issue.

Comment: You never call `updateGrid` so the value never changes. If you want it to just use the `size` you pass down as `rows` and `cols` then don't put it in state.

Comment: Your picross component doesn't respond to changes in the `rows` and `cols` props. The value passed to `useState` is only used on the very first render. You need to use `updateGrid` and handle changes to `rows` and `cols`, probably using a `useEffect` or similar, or deriving the grid directly from the props and avoiding this state entirely.

Comment: @CollinD OP should just not put the grid in state at all, it's purely derived from props.

Comment: Since it's a picross component, the data is most likely intended to change later. In a picross grid, you enter numbers. That would likely end up being state, so OP is probably setting that up. I specifically called out avoiding state in my comment too though :)